# How to make your app show in openWith or share with audio tracks

Tags: android, ios, flutter, media-player

I am trying to create a music player using flutter and I want to make it show on openWith screens and share screens  whenever an audio track is selected to be opened or shared or when the system output a list of defaults to chose from when setting a default for audio tracks.

I am using multiple android/iOS plugins in an interconnected way, and would like not to have to rely more on plugin as it really drops the performance and create certain lag that damages the UX.

is there a way to do this in dart directly ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent

The only thing you need to do is add extra configuration in your AndroidManifest.xml and Info.plist. See the example page of the plugin:

https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent#-example-tab-

Edit: I see you didn't want to rely on extra plugins. Sadly there isn't a way to do this without adding native code to your project.